# How to suppress shared aws credentials in development-mode app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, credentials

In order to use the aws command-line tool, I have aws credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials`.

When I run my app locally, I want it to require the correct IAM permissions for the app; I want it to read these permissions from environment variables.

What has happened is that even without those environment variables defined - even without the permissions defined - my app allows calls to aws which should not be allowed, because it's running on a system with developer credentials.

How can I run my app on my system (not in a container), without blowing away the credentials I need for the aws command-line, but have the app ignore those credentials?  I've tried setting the AWS_PROFILE environment variable to a non-existent value in my start script but that did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use named profiles, and run 2 sets of credentials eg DEV and PROD.

When you want to run production profile, run `export AWS_PROFILE=PROD`

Then return to the DEV credentials in the same way.

The trick here is to have no default credentials at all,  and only use named profiles.  Remove the credentials named `default` in the credentials file, and replace with only the named profiles.

See
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks!  Works great.  `aws configure --profile DEV`